# Normal function in Extbase controller

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Is it possible to write a normal function in the controller?

I want to clean up my code a bit, so I want to write some methods for repeated code segments, but I don't want to create a special class.

How is it possible to do this?

If I do a normal

```
private function xyz () {}
```

I got a `function not found` error.

Comment: Please show more code if the answer below does not help you.

Comment: Please invest some time in providing properly formatted questions with a better ortography and punctuation. Keep in mind that one day another person will have the same problem and wants to benefit from your question and the answers. Don't depend on others fixing your posts, be a good example yourself. You don't need to use TYPO3 in the title of the post if you're tagging it with "typo3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `protected`, not `private` unless you have very good reasons to do so. Anyway, defining additional methods work fine for me.

You need to call this method with `$this->xyz()`.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution might be using an abstract class if you want to share methods accross controllers:

```
abstract class AbstractController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController{
    protected function myFunction(){}
}
```

Your controllers inherit from the abstract class and will have all methods available:

```
class FirstController extends AbstractController {
    public function firstAction(){
        // has access to myFunction()
    }
}

class SecondController extends AbstractController {
    public function secondAction(){
        // has access to myFunction()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this hint I Know this possibility but isn't it like in java that I only can extend one other class?

Comment: Yes it is indeed, but as the `AbstractController` itself extends the `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController`, you'll have all methods and properties of the TYPO3 context available as usual.